# CÓMO HACER PARA NO MOSTRAR ELEMENTO UNDEFINED

Tags: javascript, html, undefined, innerhtml

En una constante tengo almacenada la plantilla HTML para cada carta de pokemon.
Quiero que en cada carta muestre los tipos de pokemon, que en algunos casos es sólo uno y en otros dos... El problema es que cuando el pokemon solo tiene un tipo, el segundo me lo muestra como "undefined" y no puedo hacer que directamente estos cuadros sin definir los ignore y no los muestre... ¿hay forma de arreglarlo?

```
<div class="pokeTypeContainer">
      <div class="pokeType">
          <div class="types" style="color:${typeColors[types[0].type.name]}">
          ${types[0].type.name}  <br>
          </div>
          <div class="types" style="color:${typeColors[types[1]?.type.name]}">
          ${types[1]?.type.name}
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Lo que quiero es que el segundo div class "types" si es undefined no lo muestre.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tendrás que ofrecer más contexto para poder incluir un condicional que verifique que el segundo tipo no es del tipo undefined y así evitar la aparición de todo el div.  Con lo que has puesto poco se puede hacer, pues el div permanecerá allí aunque consigas quitar el texto undefined

Comment: claro, es lo que pensaba... ya que el div lo tengo de esta manera porque se traen los datos de un fetch y las cartas las imprimo en plantilla de HTML porque sino no las recorría correctamente...

Answer (score 1):

lo pude solucionar asignando una variable al fragmento de HTML. Primero como una variable vacía y reasignandole el valor si este correspondiera:

```
   var secondType = ''; 
      var secondType = `<div class="types" style="color:${typeColors[types[1]?.type.name]}">
      ${types[1]?.type.name}
      </div>
      `;

    if (types[1]?.type.name == undefined){
      secondType = ''; 
    }
```